# Free Web Forwarding without Nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, cloudflare

I have a site running Google App Engine and using [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/overview.html) (a free CDN proxy, using its own nameserver).

This leaves me with no options for the root domain.
App Engine does not support naked domains, and CloudFlare doesn't support web forwarding.

All forwarding options that I've seen, including my registrar's, only work if the domain's nameservers are set to them.

Does anyone know of a free service that will send HTTP 301 (or 302) redirects without forcing me to change my nameservers?
(I'd make an `A` record for `@` pointing to their server)

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done trough .htaccess file

Comment: Read the question. I'm aware of that.  I don't have any servers that I can associate with the naked domain.